# Running the Sort example on Hadoop (single-node cluster)?

Tags: hadoop

I have installed Hadoop single-node cluster 1.0.1 on mac os  and run an example using the material of the tutorial I found on this site:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brandonwerner/archive/2011/11/13/how-to-set-up-hadoop-on-os-x-lion-10-7.aspx

Now I am trying to run the Sort example on Hadoop. It needs Sequential files as input. Could anyone please help me running the Sort example? (or giving me some more info on how to generate the Sequential files as input).

Thank you in advance.. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're talking about the TeraSort example, in which case this article gives step by step instructions:

- http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2011/04/09/benchmarking-and-stress-testing-an-hadoop-cluster-with-terasort-testdfsio-nnbench-mrbench/#terasort-benchmark-suite